# Evaluate an definite integral

Tags: calculus

Let $f'(x)=\frac{192x^3}{2+\sin^4{\pi x}}$for all $x\in R,$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0.$
If $\int \limits_\frac{1}{2}^1$ 
$f(x)dx$ belongs to 
$\left[m ,M\right],$  then the possible values of m and M are
a)$m=13 , M=24$ \
b)$m=\frac{1}{4}, M=\frac{1}{2}$ \
c)$m=-11 , M=0$ \
d)$m=1 , M=12$

I tried to integrate $f'(x)$ to get $f(x)$ but the integral is very difficult so i tried to determine the range of $f(x)$ where 
$x$ belongs to $\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$
then evaluate the integral but also could not do that.

Answer (score 2):

By taking the largest possible numerator and smallest possible denominator in the interval $[1/2,1]$, we find that $f'(x) \leq \frac{192}{2} = 96.$  Since $f(1/2) = 0$, $f(x)$ can't grow any faster than $96(x-1/2)$, so your integral is less than

$$\int_{1/2}^1 96(x-1/2) \; dx = 12.$$

So there's a possible value for $M$.  Similarly, you can find $m$.

Comment: do you mean the $\frac{47}{4}$ is a possible value of M ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: ok , how did you get but the question is multi choose and the answers do not include this value

Comment: There are lots of different ways to bound integrals.  Since you've given no context, we have no way of guessing which method is appropriate here.  E.g., you could approximate the integral with Taylor series.  I could type out a page doing just that, but then you'd respond that you don't know Taylor series.  You should have posted the whole question and what class it is.

Comment: i have edited the question and mentioned the possible answers

Comment: @HussienMohamed So -- if I understand B.Goddard's reasoning -- they got "just under 12" for _an_ upper-bound of the integral ($M$). Technically, I don't think that rules any of the options out yet (although (d) looks plausible). Now repeat the process to find _a_ candidate for $m$ (presumably by looking for the smallest numerator and largest denominator of $f'$).

Comment: @TripeHound One problem is that I can't divide.  Those $94$'s should be $96$'s.  Edit in progress.